# Struggling with making selenium wait until a link is clickable - getting 'is not clickable at(x, y)' errors

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

There is a website I'm testing on that puts up a gray loading div when the site is processing. The problem is that the div is there immediately at the website load and the only way you can tell it's running is that the inline CSS style changes.

basically when running it's:

`<div id="loading" class="loading hide" style="display: block;">text</div>`

when not running it's:

`<div id="loading" class="loading hide" style="display: none;">text</div>`

How can I have selenium wait after it clicks a link until the inline style changes? I'm using python and the chrome webdriver.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create custom wait conditions :

```
class element_has_style(object):
  """An expectation for checking that an element has a particular style.

  locator - used to find the element
  returns the WebElement once it has the particular style
  """
  def __init__(self, locator, style):
    self.locator = locator
    self.style = style

  def __call__(self, driver):
    element = driver.find_element(*self.locator)   # Finding the referenced element
    if self.style in element.get_attribute("style"):
        return element
    else:
        return False

# Wait until an element with id='loading' has style 'display: none;'
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
element = wait.until(element_has_style((By.ID, 'loading'), "display: none;"))
```

driver will wait until the element has specific style.
for more info check this [link](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html)

Comment: You don't even need a custom wait method... all you have to wait for is the element `(By.ID, 'loading')` to be invisible using `WebDriverWait` using `invisibility_of_element_located`. See [the docs](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html).

Comment: That could be true , it depends on how the page works, sometimes that does not work out well enough @JeffC